# Fluid debugging - output all variables

Tags: debugging, typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I try to output all variables from my view like this:

```
<f:debug title="all"> {_all} </f:debug>
```

But I only get this output:

[image]

I used to get an array which I can open and inspect deeper.

Why does it render like this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Plz remove the spaces before and after {_all}.
You should have:

```
<f:debug title="all">{_all}</f:debug>
```